# Minimal number of swaps?

Tags: big-o

There are N characters in a string of types A and B in the array (same amount of each type). What is the minimal number of swaps to make sure that no two adjacent chars are same if we can only swap two adjacent characters ? 
For example, input is:

```
AAAABBBB
```

The minimal number of swaps is 6 to make the array ABABABAB. But how would you solve it for any kind of input ? I can only think of O(N^2) solution. Maybe some kind of sort ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need the modified array?  Your example has another "goal" array of `BABABABA` and, for general input strings, it is not necessarily obvious which solution a minimum swap count would correspond to.

Comment: @phs No, it is irrelevant which solution is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If we need just to count swaps**, then we can do it with **O(N)**.

Let's assume for simplicity that array X of N elements should become ABAB... .

```
GetCount()
    swaps = 0, i = -1, j = -1
    for(k = 0; k < N; k++)
        if(k % 2 == 0)
            i = FindIndexOf(A, max(k, i))
            X[k] <-> X[i]
            swaps += i - k
        else
            j = FindIndexOf(B, max(k, j))
            X[k] <-> X[j]
            swaps += j - k
    return swaps

FindIndexOf(element, index)
    while(index < N)
        if(X[index] == element) return index
        index++
    return -1; // should never happen if count of As == count of Bs
```

Basically, we run from left to right, and if a misplaced element is found, it gets exchanged with the correct element (e.g. `abBbbbA** --> abAbbbB**`) in `O(1)`. At the same time swaps are counted as if the sequence of adjacent elements would be swapped instead. Variables `i` and `j` are used to cache indices of next `A` and `B` respectively, to make sure that *all calls together* of FindIndexOf are done in `O(N)`.

**If we need to sort by swaps** then we cannot do better than **O(N^2)**.

The rough idea is the following. Let's consider your sample: `AAAABBBB`. One of `B`s needs O(N) swaps to get to the A **B** ... position, another `B` needs O(N) to get to A B A **B** ... position, etc. So we get O(N^2) at the end.

Comment: I think there is a better solution. For the sample, I can count the number of adjacent As, that's 3. I'm in halfway and I know there's gonna be four times B, so I can perform this formula = N*(N+1)/2 and it would give the right answer, but only and only if the first half of the array is of the same characters. And I don't how to modify it to work for any input.

Comment: Also notice, that I only need the minimal number of swaps as output, not the modified array.

Comment: You may _know_ the final order in O(N) in your case, but to get to that order by swapping _neighbours only_ you need O(N^2). N*(N+1)/2 is still O(N^2).

Comment: -1: you have only attempted to prove that the answer is `O(n^2)`. This does not mean that getting that answer is also `O(n^2)`. The question asks for the number of steps, not for the list of steps.

Comment: @IVlad Though I agree with you that it does not answer the question, the general idea is correct (again, I'm not sure it is actually O(N^2)). +1

Comment: @IVlad Do you mean that the rough idea is not sufficient and I should better copy-past bubble sorting complexity analysis?

Comment: He means that your answer does not prove that O(N^2) is the minimum.

Comment: I'm currently thinking about O(N).

Comment: @AlexD - you are confusing the order of the **answer** with the order of the **optimal algorithm to find the answer**. If the answer to a problem is `n*n`, the order of the answer is `O(n^2)`, but the order of the algorithm is `O(1)`: `print(n*n)`. Also, you haven't given a rigurous enough proof for your statement, nor answered the OP's question: what is the optimal algorithm to get the answer?

Comment: @CLU Actually, I also suspect O(N).

Comment: @TT_ Oh, sorry then. I thought it is quite straightforward. It is, roughly speaking, like sorting (1 3 5 7 2 4 6 8) with bubble sort.

Comment: @AlexD No, that's the point. The simpler algorithm can exist.

Comment: @TT_ - the OP asks for an algorithm to find the minimal number of moves. Even if the minimal number of swaps is always `O(n^2)`, there is no reason an algorithm that finds this minimal number cannot be `O(n)`.

Comment: @IVlad Ah, I see your point. But I think the OP needs an estimate for number of moves.

Comment: @TT_ - not an estimate, the exact number as far as I understand. He needs a faster than `O(n^2)` algorithm to find this number. Running bubble sort is `O(n^2)`. The OP needs better.

Comment: When you are applying the bubble sort, you are solving more difficult problem. At least, you did not prove the original problem is as difficult as sorting.

Comment: @IVlad Ah, got it! It might be linear indeed. Let me think a bit.

Comment: If I apply quicksort or mergesort, I get O(N log N) but I seriously think there can be O(N). I'm currently playing with chess figures and trying to find the formula or something...

Comment: If you have the bubble sort solution, it's pretty easy to get `O(n)` from that.

Comment: @IVlad I just typing the O(n) answer.

Comment: Actually, I seem changing my mind... I am trying to solve it recursively and now it looks like O(n^2), not O(n) as I hoped.

Comment: @IVlad It should be O(N), I just needs to formulate it accurately.

Comment: @AlexD Have you came up with something ?

Comment: @CLU Yes, it is O(N), I'm working on a compact answer.

Comment: @AlexD I'm sorry, but what do you mean by "if(k is odd)" and " X[j] <-> X[k]" ?

Comment: @CLU `if(k % 2 == 1)` then swap values of `X[j]` and `X[k]`.

Comment: @AlexD lol now I know what are ODD numbers, sorry (english is not my native...)

Comment: @AlexD X[i] <-> X[k] - you actually don't have to swap elements to calculate the swaps, or do you ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47101/discussion-between-alexd-and-clu)

Comment: I'm not sure yet, but isn't your `FindIndexOf` method `O(n)`? So the whole thing is still `O(n^2)`?

Comment: @IVlad _All calls together_ to `FindIndex` are `O(n)`, due to cached `i`, `j`. We never decrease the index to start search from.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that if any solution would swap two instances of the same letter, then we can find a better solution by dropping that swap, which necessarily has no effect.  An optimal solution therefore only swaps differing letters.

Let's view the string of letters as an array of indices of one kind of letter (arbitrarily chosen, say `A`) into the string.  So `AAAABBBB` would be represented as `[0, 1, 2, 3]` while `ABABABAB` would be `[0, 2, 4, 6]`.

We know two instances of the same letter will never swap in an optimal solution.  This lets us always safely identify the first (left-most) instance of `A` with the first element of our index array, the second instance with the second element, etc.  It also tells us our array is always in sorted order at each step of an optimal solution.

Since each step of an optimal solution swaps differing letters, we know our index array evolves at each step only by incrementing or decrementing a single element at a time.

An initial string of length `n = 2k` will have an array representation `A` of length `k`.  An optimal solution will transform this array to either

```
ODDS = [1, 3, 5, ... 2k]
```

or

```
EVENS = [0, 2, 4, ... 2k - 1]
```

Since we know in an optimal solution instances of a letter do not pass each other, we can conclude an optimal solution must spend `min(abs(ODDS[0] - A[0]), abs(EVENS[0] - A[0]))` swaps to put the first instance in correct position.

By realizing the `EVENS` or `ODDS` choice is made only once (not once per letter instance), and summing across the array, we can count the minimum number of needed swaps as

```
define count_swaps(length, initial, goal)
  total = 0
  for i from 0 to length - 1
    total += abs(goal[i] - initial[i])
  end
  return total
end

define count_minimum_needed_swaps(k, A)
  return min(count_swaps(k, A, EVENS), count_swaps(k, A, ODDS))
end
```

Notice the number of loop iterations implied by `count_minimum_needed_swaps` is `2 * k = n`; it runs in `O(n)` time.

By noting which term is smaller in `count_minimum_needed_swaps`, we can also tell which of the two goal states is optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know N, you can simply write a loop that generates the values with no swaps needed.

```
#define N 4
char array[N + N];

for (size_t z = 0; z < N + N; z++)
{
    array[z] = 'B' - ((z & 1) == 0);
}

return 0;   // The number of swaps
```

Comment: -1: did you even read the question? Also, your code always returns 0.

Comment: Yes. Exactly.  No swaps are needed. Hence the minimum is zero.

Answer (score 0):

@Nemo and @AlexD are right. The algorithm is order n^2. @Nemo misunderstood that we are looking for a reordering where two adjacent characters are not the same, so we can not use that if A is after B they are out of order.

Lets see the minimum number of swaps.

We dont care if our first character is A or B, because we can apply the same algorithm but using A instead of B and viceversa everywhere. So lets assume that the length of the word `WORD_N` is 2N, with N As and N Bs, starting with an A. (I am using length 2N to simplify the calculations).

What we will do is try to move the next B right to this A, without taking care of the positions of the other characters, because then we will have reduce the problem to reorder a new word `WORD_{N-1}`. Lets also assume that the next B is not just after A if the word has more that 2 characters, because then the first step is done and we reduce the problem to the next set of characters, `WORD_{N-1}`.

The next B should be as far as possible to be in the worst case, so it is after half of the word, so we need $N-1$ swaps to put this B after the A (maybe less than that). Then our word can be reduced to `WORD_N = [A B WORD_{N-1}]`.

We se that we have to perform this algorithm as most N-1 times, because the last word (`WORD_1`) will be already ordered. Performing the algorithm N-1 times we have to make

N_swaps = (N-1)*N/2.

where N is half of the lenght of the initial word.

Lets see why we can apply the same algorithm for `WORD_{N-1}` also assuming that the first word is A. In this case it matters than the first word should be the same as in the already ordered pair. We can be sure that the first character in `WORD_{N-1}` is A because it was the character just next to the first character in our initial word, ant if it was B the first work can perform only a swap between these two words and or none and we will already have `WORD_{N-1}` starting with the same character than `WORD_{N}`, while the first two characters of `WORD_{N}` are different at the cost of almost 1 swap.

Comment: No, I have explained two times why this line of thought is wrong. I know how to solve it in `O(n)`, and others have already posted how. And this isn't even my question, which just goes to show that you haven't even bothered to read it properly. I say it for the 235235th time: just because the answer is `O(n^2)`, does **NOT** mean that the algorithm must also be `O(n^2)`. Please read the discussions that took place before telling someone they 'have no clue' and before you post the exact same wrong thing a day later.

Comment: @IVlad You are right. It is O(n).  I see the point now. I apologize.

Answer (score -1):

I think this answer is similar to the answer by phs, just in Haskell. The idea is that the resultant-indices for `A`'s (or `B`'s) are known so all we need to do is calculate how far each starting index has to move and sum the total.

Haskell code:

```
Prelude Data.List> let is = elemIndices 'B' "AAAABBBB" 
                   in minimum 
                   $ map (sum . zipWith ((abs .) . (-)) is) [[1,3..],[0,2..]]
6 --output
```